# Unable to install rails 2.3.11 from netbeans 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans-6.9

How to install specific version of rails from Netbeans ?

I have already installed rails 2.3.11 from command prompt.

But still it's not showing rails 2.3.11 inside netbeans toole -> rubygems.

How to fix this problem ? Or How to install rails 2.3.11 from netbeans ? So it shows rails 2.3.11 into tools -> rubygems.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems do you encounter? We don't have magical psychic abilities :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed

Gem Home:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Gem Path:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

in netbeans.

It worked for me.